# hg convert from Subversion on macOS -- could not load Subversion python bindings?

Tags: python, macos, svn, mercurial, tortoisehg

I want to convert a subversion repository to mercurial on macOS.  I've made a local copy of the svn repo.  Then I tried

```
hg convert --source-type svn --dest-type hg srcPath dstPath
```

and got

```
could not load Subversion python bindings
abort: srcPath: missing or unsupported repository
```

I found [this page on the convert extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ConvertExtension), which talks about needing Subversion python bindings.  One thing it says is

> Bindings are included with the TortoiseHg distribution package and the Win32 InnoSetup (non-MSI) binaries for Mercurial, so if you install either of them you don't need to install additional packages.

Well, I installed TortoiseHG, which is an application on macOS, but I don't see how that helps.

It also says

> For Mac OS X, the easiest way is to install the CollabNet Subversion build, and then copy the content of /opt/subversion/lib/svn-python to the site-package directory of the Python installation.

So I follow their link to the CollabNet Subversion build, and I see offerings for Windows, Linux, and Solaris, but nothing about macOS.

I also tried installing [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org) and installing the `subversion-python27bindings` package.  Didn't help.  (In case it's not obvious, I'm not familiar with Python and have only the vaguest idea what bindings are.)

I'm lost.

Answer (score 3):

I got it to work by using MacPorts to install the `hgsubversion` extension, and then using that to clone the svn repository, rather than using `hg convert`.

Comment: As of 2021, this does not work with recent versions of TortoiseHG, or Mercurial in general: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/HgSubversion mentions that "hgsubversion isn't being actively developed and may not work with the latest version of Mercurial. As an example, it does not support Python 3." I tried it, and this is correct. Mercurial uses Python 3, and hgsubversion produces tons of errors on Python 3 ...